# brightening frames extracted from video

Tags: ffmpeg

the problem is:

I use variants of `ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\T1\Downloads\z\video.ts" -map :0 -vf fps=4 -qscale:v 2 "a:\screencaps\video\video.mkv %d.jpg"` to extract frames and I know that ffmpeg can brighten video but using the inputs I've found for example `-vf curves=strong_contrast` found here has had no brightening effect on extracted images. is it possible to brighten images as they're created?

any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the [curves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves) filter use the `lighter` preset instead of `strong_contrast`. Or make your own curves in Photoshop, export the `.acv` file, and use the `psfile` option: `-vf curves=psfile=custom.acv`.

There are many methods to lighten/brighten the image. A few examples of other filters:

- [colorlevels](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorlevels): `-vf colorlevels=rimax=0.902:gimax=0.902:bimax=0.902`
- [eq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq): `-vf eq=brightness=0.1`